# App Getting Crash immediately after the installation

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, android-studio

[image]

I'm getting this error when I'm running the app in android and after the successful build installed the app in device but immediate crash.

`React Native version :- 0.63.5`

`midSDK version :- 24`

`targetSDK & complieSDK version :- 24`

`gradle version :- 6.9`

When I'm creating the latest version of project It's working perfectly.

Thank you for reaching out!

Comment: Seems like a linking error. Make sure all your modules are correctly linked and also make sure you have this line in dependencies in build.gradle `implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+" `

Comment: already I have that dependency and also check the modules are correctly linked.